# Does not show newly created module in Layout

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I'm trying to list my newly created module`(account_test)` that copied from `"account"` module in **OpenCart 2.x** (`account` module shows in backend `system->design->layouts-> edit home layout`). I have duplicated all account php & tpl files to account_test & tpl files and change all references from `account` to `account_test` in both `admin & catalog` `module/language/view` folders.

[image: Layouts]

Also, I noticed in `admin\controller\design\layout.php` the if statement which add only `Account & Category` modules to Layouts setting:

```
if ($this->config->has($code . '_status') || $module_data) {
                $data['extensions'][] = array(
                    'name'   => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
                    'code'   => $code,
                    'module' => $module_data
                );

            }
```

If i remove the if condition :

```
        $data['extensions'][] = array(
            'name'   => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'code'   => $code,
            'module' => $module_data
        );
```

It will add all modules to layouts view, but none of them working except old modules

[image: layouts removed if]

Stuck in this for few days, Any ideas to list newly created module to layouts admin section and front end?

Answer (score 1):

Is you module get installed or not? If you followed correctly then it must be listed in `admin->extension->modules`. And then from there you have to first install it and then enable it. And also make sure the controller file named properly.

**Edit**

`$this->config->has($code . '_status')` checks whether you module is installed or not i.e. is it in setting table or not. Check in setting table for your module code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I found out the issue was typos in my code :)!!